# На c++ нужно сделать 20 повторных операции. при этом каждая следующая операция должна произойти после ввода слова пользователя

Tags: c++

```
for i in range(0,19)
   x = input()
   print(x)
```

нужна такая же схема, для c++. Пока пользователь не введет слово, следующий цикл не произойдет

Comment: `cin >> x; cout << x; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
string str;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
cin >> str;
cout << str << endl;
}
```

Это самый минимум, если ещё нужно учесть неправильный ввод пользователя, то можно [прочесть это](https://ravesli.com/urok-72-obrabotka-nekorrektnogo-vvoda-cherez-std-cin/).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
char a;
int b=0;
do {
printf("Введите Слово: ");
    cin>>a; 
    b++;
} while (b <> 20);
```

Comment: Спасибо ВСЕМ за обсуждение моего вопроса...